# Why am I sleep deprived?

Tags: twins

My 11 mo twins are difficult to handle and I feel very sleepy. I am sleep deprived. I find it so hard to concentrate. Also my tiny baby constantly beats and pokes my other twin.

Comment: Can you separate them? For example put one at one end of the crib and the other at the other so their feet are pointing towards each other. Maybe two play pens or one in the pen and one in a bouncy swing etc?

Comment: [coping with sleep deprivation](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/10533/methods-for-reducing-or-coping-with-sleep-deprivation) question

Comment: If i separate them they will scream, kick , cry and will yearn for each other as if they are soulmates . When they come together, they will be so happy and will play together for may be 3 minutes and then again will start pulling each.there's hair and slapping, biting etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All parents are sleep deprived; parents of twins even more so.

If you can get help for a couple of hours every day during which you can take a long nap, it will help to reduce your sleep deficit.

Some hospitals have information on coping with twins and volunteers who will help the parents of multiple gestations. Perhaps you can ask at the hospital where your twins were born, or your doctor or HV; or perhaps you have some friends who have asked if and how they can help. Don't be shy; tell them you'd love to get some much needed sleep. Have them put the word out to your friends. Most people are happy to help, and if five people help once a week, that's significant. If you see a social worker for any reason, ask there, too.

Sleep when your babies sleep, and optimize their sleep schedules as much as possible.

Comment: "Sleep when your babies sleep." `+1` from me to this. *Rule No.1 for young parents:* ***When your children sleep, so do you.*** No matter when and where, and no matter what's on your list, you drop down and nap until a child wakes you. Because, when your children are awake, so are you.

Comment: I agree completely but sometimes feel so frustrated especially when both the babies keep hurting each other.